# Grab me a/that glass/cup vs. Bring me a/that glass/cup

Tags: phrase-request

**Scenario:** you are sitting on a chair and using your laptop and want your little daughter to get you *a/that cup/glass of something* that both you can see it there on the counter.

Which one sounds better:

> *Grab me a/that glass/cup* or *Bring me a/that glass/cup*? (of something e.g water)

How do you say that in everyday US English? more than way of saying so is definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like them all, and they are basically interchangeable. Everything I say in the remainder of this is subtle. "Grab me a cup" is a bit informal. "Get" is somewhere between informal and neutral, and "bring" is somewhere between neutral and formal. To my ear, "bring" sounds a little more polite than the others as well; it's definitely the one I would use with my boss or with someone I didn't know too well.

If it were someone I knew better, I think I'd use bring if I were making an imposition on the person (asking them for a genuine favor) and grab if I were implying that I was not asking for much. ("Can you please bring me a cup of tea" vs. "While you're in the kitchen, grab me a cup.")

Comment: Yes, this kind of detail is what I'm looking for. I didn't mention *"get"* but I would like to know your opinion about it if I'm not asking much.

Comment: it is more standard than "grab" but I would use it in more or less the same places I would use "grab" as described in the above answer. I personally really like "grab" but "get" is more common.

Answer (score 1):

If it's one particular glass you can both see on the counter, use *that glass*.

If there are several glasses on the counter, and you don't care which one she brings you, use *a glass*.

Comment: My first choice would be *Get me that [glass,cup].* Saying *Bring me that [glass,cup],* sounds a little too polite for me, and it might come out as *Bring me that [glass,cup], please,* instead. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @J.R. I interpreted the question the same as you did at first, but I think the OP is asking about the difference between "grab" and "bring", not the difference between "a glass" and "that glass" (or even the difference between "glass" and "cup").

Comment: Sorry, it seems I have a problem explaining myself! I'll keep this in mind from now on. It's about "bring vs. grab" not about cup vs. glass as they are both the same in both sentences. I included a/that just in case they make a difference.

Comment: @learner - Yes, please spend a few minutes making sure your questions are clear about the crux of the question. Comments are limited to 600 characters; questions aren't. There's no need to rush and waste people's time by having them type answers you don't need.